# $routeProvider config route throwing 'Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm writing routing logic using ngRoute of angular JS. The following is my code.

index.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function config($routeProvider, $httpProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider, $tooltipProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['content-type'] = "application/json";
  }

  angular
    .module('pacman', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.validate',
                      'angular-cache', 'angular-loading-bar', 'angular-md5', 'rt.iso8601', 'ngAnimate']
            )
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'cfpLoadingBarProvider', '$tooltipProvider', config])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$modalStack', '$cookies']);
})();
```

app.controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'app/components/landingpage/landingpage.html',
      controller: 'appController'
    });
  }

  function appController($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.submitLogin = function() {
      alert("Successfully loggedIn");
    };
  }

  angular
    .module('pacman')
    .controller('appController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', appController])
    .config(['$routeProvider', config]);
})();
```

notFound.controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/404', {
      templateUrl: 'app/components/notFound/404page.html',
      controller: 'notFoundController'
    });
  }
  function notFoundController($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    debugger;
  }
  angular
    .module('pacman')
    .controller('notFoundController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', notFoundController])
    .config(['$routeProvider', config]);
})();
```

My code is a simple app. I'm trying to load different controllers based on routes. However at the time of loading the app, in the last controller's '$routeProvider' it throws an error

Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string

I have no clue how to figure out the problem. Any leads would be appreciated.
The following is my library bundle order.

```
'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
'node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js',
'node_modules/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.js',
'node_modules/angular-cache/dist/angular-cache.js',
'node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
'node_modules/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js',
'node_modules/angular-ui-validate/dist/validate.js',
'node_modules/chart.js/Chart.js',
'node_modules/angular-md5/angular-md5.js',
'node_modules/angular-iso8601/dist/angular-iso8601.js',
'node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
'node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js',
'node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js',
'node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
```

Kindly help.

Comment: So probably somewhere in your code you declare `fn()` or something, but I can't see it. Are you sure you implemented all the code in your question?

Comment: @Goldenowner Yes, it is the full question. The error says that its receiving a string, but expecting a function. It throws error when it encounters $routeProvider.when method in the last controller.js. No matter order the controllers are.

Comment: @Goldenowner I ran into this error when I added more that 1 route and controller.

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Comment: Posted my answer causing the issue. See if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your `index.js` where you define the `run` method on your angular app.

```
angular
    .module('pacman', []) // removed dependencies for brevity
    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$modalStack', '$cookies']);
```

The last argument in the array passed to `run` should be a function but you **forgot to pass a function**. Change your `run` to add some implementation like below or remove the `run` if you don't see any use for it.

```
angular.module('pacman', []) // removed dependencies for brevity

       .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$modalStack', '$cookies',

                function($rootScope,$location,$modalStack,$cookies){
                    // some statements here
            }]);
```

Comment: You saved my day. I'm new to ng. So couldnt figure it out. Thanks @Arkantos

Comment: What does it it expect a callback for run? I thought it was optional. Can you please explain?

Comment: `run()` can be used to initialize you angular module. The function that you pass to `run()` will be executed exactly once when the module is created.

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS file declaration must come before the jquery in your index.html

'node_modules/angular/angular.js',

'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',

Comment: Nope. Ideally `jQuery.js` should come before `angular.js` in case you wish to use `jQuery` instead of the default `jQLite` implementation

Comment: But i'm still able to build and run app. I don't think this is the problem.